# Difference between get() and getall() in Scrapy and Interpreting Code Output

Tags: python, json, parsing, web-scraping, scrapy

Can anyone help me here?

I have this code, but when I use `get()` it just captures the first products of each page and the JSON file comes the way I want it. When I use `getall()` it takes all the products I need, but the JSON file is different.

For example, I have 50 pages and 50 products per page for a total of 2500 products. In the `get()` method it takes only 50, in the `getall()` method it takes all, but with a strange JSON file.

I want the same JSON output as the `get()` method, but capturing all products just like the `getall()` method

I'll attach the code and prints of the JSON files

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import scrapy
from scrapy.exceptions import CloseSpider


class ProdutosSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'produtos'
    allowed_domains = ['www.allpartsnet.com.br']
    start_urls = [
        "https://www.allpartsnet.com.br/buscapagina?fq=B%3a1228&O=OrderByNameASC&PS=50&sl=5d58b484-137e-4091-92ca-29d2e0c70f85&cc=1&sm=0&PageNumber=0"]
    page = 0

    def parse(self, response):

        if len(response.xpath("//*[@class='QD prateleira row qd-xs n1colunas']")) == 0:
            raise CloseSpider('No more products to scrape...')

        for produtos in response.xpath("//*[@class='QD prateleira row qd-xs n1colunas']"):
            yield {
                'nome': produtos.xpath("//*[@class='shelf-product-name ']/a/@title").getall(),
                'url': produtos.xpath("//*[@class='shelf-product-name ']/a/@href").getall(),
                'valor': produtos.xpath("//*[@class='old-price']/text()").getall(),
                'valor_desc': produtos.xpath("//*[@class='best-price']/text()").getall()
            }

        self.page += 1
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url=f'https://www.allpartsnet.com.br/buscapagina?fq=B%3a1228&O=OrderByNameASC&PS=50&sl=5d58b484-137e-4091-92ca-29d2e0c70f85&cc=1&sm=0&PageNumber={self.page}',
            callback=self.parse
        )
```

`get()`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5dOj.png

ALT+SHIFT+F

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ew1lg.png

`getall()`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8J0o.png

ALT+SHIFT+F

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xG1yL.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `.get()` will always return the first item your selector found, as a string.

The method `.getall()` will always return a list of strings, with ALL the items your selector found.

[More here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#id1)

> I want the same JSON output as the get () method, but capturing all products just like the getall () method

It seem to me that the problem you are having is not with the `get()/getall()` method, but with the XPath. You should replace the lines `produtos.xpath("...").getall()` with `produtos.xpath("...").get()`, since you are iterating between all the selectors in `produtos`.

However, when you use the selector like this:

```
"//*[@class='shelf-product-name ']/a/@title"
```

you are calling the descendant-or-self (`//`) axis on the whole document instead of in the context of the current node (`.//`).

Try this and let me know if it helped:

```
   for produtos in response.xpath("//*[@class='QD prateleira row qd-xs n1colunas']"):
        yield {
            'nome': produtos.xpath(".//*[@class='shelf-product-name ']/a/@title").get(),
            'url': produtos.xpath(".//*[@class='shelf-product-name ']/a/@href").get(),
            'valor': produtos.xpath(".//*[@class='old-price']/text()").get(),
            'valor_desc': produtos.xpath(".//*[@class='best-price']/text()").get()
        }
```

*PS.: In the future, please don't use images to show your code/output/logs, always copy and paste a piece of it in the question*

### Edit:

Sorry, I haven't actually checked the page before. The problem is still with the Xpath though. This selector selects a single item:

```
for produtos in response.xpath("//*[@class='QD prateleira row qd-xs n1colunas']"):
```

So you don't really iterate over anything, since there is a single return. Try replacing it with

```
for produtos in response.xpath("//*[@class='QD prateleira row qd-xs n1colunas']/ul/li[not(@class='helperComplement')]"):
```

in addition to the suggestions I previously mention.

Comment: Thanks @renatodvc now it worked. I don't know if I understood it well, but I needed to be more specific about xpath? Thank you again! Helped me a lot!

Comment: Glad to hear Lucas. Your XPath was selecting a single [parent] element, but you want to iterate between the rows (of items), so the selector must point to the rows. The one I suggest returns 50 items, instead of one. From there you iterate on each node and extract the data you need. A [reading suggestion](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/developer-tools.html).